# Why is the token_for_business field not showing on the signed_request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/. Currently, I'm able to get the token_for_business through the field on the user node, but not through the signed_request, it's not there. My app is associated to a business though. I'm not sure why it's not showing.

Comment: Is the user logged in to the app already at this point? Please explain what your _exact_ scenario is here, which steps are performed in what order, and when/where you are getting the SR.

Comment: Yes, the user is already logged in, that is why I was able to get the signed_request. The signed request should contain the user information along with the token_for_business when deciphered, but it's not there. The issue happens after the I send the signed request to the server to parse it. I get the signed request from the facebook api using MessengerExtensions.getContext()

Comment: The page you linked to mentioned this only for the context of canvas apps, not anything messenger related.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense. I thought that I could also get the token for business from a messenger app. Maybe I should just keep on getting it fro the user node though it's an extra call to the graph api.